# contrast comparison

Tags: linear-model, contrasts

I have a linear model where one dv is predicted by one categorical with 4 levels. I want to check if the intercept differs from the average of the other 3 conditions.

I fit the model

```
m1 <- lm(DV ~  categorical, data = data)
```

Then I perform contrast analysis by specifying

```
K <- matrix(c(3, -1, -1, -1), 1)
t <- glht(m1, linfct = K)
```

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your approach will produce what you want because of the way the model is parameterized.  By "intercept" you are probably referring to the overall mean.  But in these ANOVA-type models the default parameterization in `lm()` sets the intercept equal to the first categorical level.  So in your model (m1), the intercept is the mean for "categorical" level 1.  The other 3 model coefficients are not means but rather the effect size of categorical levels 2, 3, and 4 relative to categorical level 1.  So your contrast is testing whether 3 times the mean of categorical level 1 is different from the sum of the effect sizes, relative to categorical level 1, of the other 3 levels.

One way to get what you want is to use sum-to-zero contrasts.  This will set the intercept to the overall mean.  These only work with factors so you will have to convert the categorical variable to a factor if you haven't already.  See `?contrasts` and `?contr.sum` for more information.

Then you can set up a contrast to test whether the sum of the effect sizes is different from zero.  This is equivalent to testing whether the overall mean differs from the average of the other 3 conditions.

```
data$categorical_factor <- factor(data$categorical))
contrasts(data$categorical_factor) <- contr.sum(4)
m2 <- lm(DV ~ categorical_factor, data = data)
summary(m2)

K2 <- matrix(c(0, -1, -1, -1), 1)
t2 <- multcomp::glht(m2, linfct = K2)
summary(t2)
```